# Unblock a file in windows from a python script

Tags: python, powershell

Could I unblock a file in windows(7), which is automatically blocked by windows (downloaded from Internet) from a python script? A WindowsError is raised when such a file is encountered. I thought of catching this exception, and running a powershell script that goes something like:

```
Parameter Set: ByPath
Unblock-File [-Path] <String[]> [-Confirm] [-WhatIf] [ <CommonParameters>]

Parameter Set: ByLiteralPath
Unblock-File -LiteralPath <String[]> [-Confirm] [-WhatIf] [ <CommonParameters>]
```

I don't know powershell scripting. But if I had one I could call it from python. Could you folks help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all you have to do is call the following command line from Python:

```
powershell.exe -Command Unblock-File -Path "c:\path\to\blocked file.ps1"
```

Comment: Point of note... `Unblock-File` is new as of Powershell 3.  OP may be running 2 since they're on Windows 7.

Comment: Good to note, but OP also mentioned the `Unblock-File` cmdlet in his original post. PowerShell 3.0 and 4.0 are both available for Windows 7 (as part of the Windows Management Framework Core package). The Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 or 4.5 are prerequisites for each version, respectively.

Comment: +1 Yepyep, just wanted to clarify for OP and future googlers.  Kind of a bummer to get your solution and then realize you're running the wrong version later. :)

Comment: Yes, it could be the case for many users. I remember updating to v3.0 when Windows Management Framework was automatically updated by Windows.

Answer (score 1):

From this page about the `Unblock-File` command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unblock-file?view=powershell-7.2

> Internally, the `Unblock-File` cmdlet removes the **Zone.Identifier** alternate data stream, which has a value of `3` to indicate that it was downloaded from the internet.

To remove an alternate data stream `ads_name` from a file `path\to\file.ext`, simply delete `path\to\file.ext:ads_name`:

```py
try:
    os.remove(your_file_path + ':Zone.Identifier')
except FileNotFoundError:
    # The ADS did not exist, it was already unblocked or
    # was never blocked in the first place
    pass
# No need to open up a PowerShell subprocess!
```

(And similarly, to check if a file is blocked you can use `os.path.isfile(your_file_path + ':Zone.Identifier')`)

In a PowerShell script, you can use `Unblock-File` for this, or simply `Remove-Item -Path $your_file_path':Zone.Identifier'`.
`Remove-Item` also has a specific flag for alternate data streams: `Remove-Item -Stream Zone.Identifier` (which you can pipe in multiple files to, or a single `-Path`)

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party . . . .
I have found that the Block status is simply an extra 'file' (stream) attached in NTFS and it can actually be accessed and somewhat manipulated by ordinary means.  These are called Alternative Data Streams.
The ADS for file blocking (internet zone designation) is called ':Zone.Identifier' and contains, I think, some useful information:

```
[ZoneTransfer]
ZoneId=3
ReferrerUrl=https://www.google.com/
HostUrl=https://imgs.somewhere.com/product/1969297/some-pic.jpg
```

All the other info I have found says to just delete this extra stream....  But, personally, I want to keep this info....    So I tried *changing* the ZoneId to 0, but it still shows as Blocked in Windows File Properties.
I settled on *moving* it to another stream name so I can still find it later.

The below script originated from a more generic script called pyADS.   I only care about deleting / changing the Zone.Identifier attached stream -- which can all be done with simple Python commands.   So this is a stripped-down version.   It has several really nice background references listed.  I am currently running the latest Windows 10 and Python 3.8+;  I make no guarantees this works on older versions.

```
import os

'''
References:
    Accessing alternative data-streams of files on an NTFS volume   https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2670/Accessing-alternative-data-streams-of-files-on-an
    Original ADS class (pyADS)                                      https://github.com/RobinDavid/pyADS
    SysInternal streams applet                                      https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/streams
    Windows: killing the Zone.Identifier NTFS alternate data stream https://wiert.me/2011/11/25/windows-killing-the-zone-identifier-ntfs-alternate-data-stream-from-a-file-to-prevent-security-warning-popup/
    Zone.Information                                                https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/6e3f7352-d11c-4d76-8c39-2516a9df36e8
    About URL Security Zones                                        https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms537183(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
    GREAT info: How Windows Determines That the File....            http://woshub.com/how-windows-determines-that-the-file-has-been-downloaded-from-the-internet/
    Dixin's Blog: Understanding File Blocking and Unblocking        https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-the-internet-file-blocking-and-unblocking

'''
class ADS2():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

    def full_filename(self, stream):
        return "%s:%s" % (self.filename, stream)

    def add_stream_from_file(self, filename):
        if os.path.exists(filename):
            with open(filename, "rb") as f: content = f.read()
            return self.add_stream_from_string(filename, content)
        else:
            print("Could not find file: {0}".format(filename))
            return False

    def add_stream_from_string(self, stream_name, bytes):
        fullname = self.full_filename(os.path.basename(stream_name))
        if os.path.exists(fullname):
            print("Stream name already exists")
            return False
        else:
            fd = open(fullname, "wb")
            fd.write(bytes)
            fd.close()
            return True

    def delete_stream(self, stream):
        try:
            os.remove(self.full_filename(stream))
            return True
        except:
            return False

    def get_stream_content(self, stream):
        fd = open(self.full_filename(stream), "rb")
        content = fd.read()
        fd.close()
        return content
```

```
def UnBlockFile(file, retainInfo=True):
    ads = ADS2(file)
    if zi := ads.get_stream_content("Zone.Identifier"):
        ads.delete_stream("Zone.Identifier")
        if retainInfo: ads.add_stream_from_string("Download.Info", zi)
```

```
### Usage:
from unblock_files import UnBlockFile
UnBlockFile(r"D:\Downloads\some-pic.jpg")
```

Before:

```
D:\downloads>dir /r
 Volume in drive D is foo
 Directory of D:\downloads

11/09/2021  10:05 AM                 8 some-pic.jpg
                                   126 some-pic.jpg:Zone.Identifier:$DATA
               1 File(s)              8 bytes

D:\downloads>more <some-pic.jpg:Zone.Identifier:$DATA
[ZoneTransfer]
ZoneId=3
ReferrerUrl=https://www.google.com/
HostUrl=https://imgs.somewhere.com/product/1969297/some-pic.jpg
```

After:

```
D:\downloads>dir /r
 Volume in drive D is foo
 Directory of D:\downloads

11/09/2021  10:08 AM                 8 some-pic.jpg
                                   126 some-pic.jpg:Download.Info:$DATA
               1 File(s)              8 bytes
```