# How to unblock a file removing the Zone Identifier so it can be written to

Tags: python

I have a script that downloads a spreadsheet from a website, but its "blocked" when its saved to a folder.  How can I clear the blocked attribute so it can be modified by the script?
In C#, I can use a Win32 API call to DeleteFile in kernel32, passing in the file name + ":Zone.Identifier" and that will clear it.  How can this be done in Python?  Ive seen references to "unblocking" a file in Python, but not sure this is the same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unblock a file in windows from a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886450/unblock-a-file-in-windows-from-a-python-script)

Comment: You could have used `File.Delete(filename + ":Zone.Identifier")` in C# as well (`os.remove(filename + ":Zone.Identifier")` in Python)